# How to use existing data from another table as foreign key, without creating a new row?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

```
internal class UserEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public UserTypeEntity UserType { get; set; } = null!;
    public AddressEntity Address { get; set; } = null!;
    public ICollection<CaseEntity> Cases { get; set; } = new HashSet<CaseEntity>();
    public ICollection<CommentEntity> Comments { get; set; } = new HashSet<CommentEntity>();
}
```

```
internal class UserTypeEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; } = null!;

    public ICollection<UserEntity> Users { get; set; } = new HashSet<UserEntity>();
}
```

```
internal abstract class GenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DataContext _context = new DataContext();

    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAllSync()
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var item = await _context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefaultAsync(predicate);
        return item ?? null!;
    }

    public virtual async Task<TEntity> SaveAsync(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var item = await GetAsync(predicate);
        if (item == null)
        {
            _context.Add(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }

        return item;
    }
}
```

```
DataContext _context = new DataContext();

UserEntity user = new UserEntity()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Email = "johndoee@example.com",
    PhoneNumber = "1234567890",
    UserType = new UserTypeEntity { TypeName = "Customer"},
    Address = new AddressEntity { StreetName = "123 Main St", PostalCode = "12345", City = "New York" }
};

UserService userService = new UserService();
var result = await userService.SaveAsync(user, x => x.Email == user.Email);
```

I want to be able to create a new User with a existing UserType. In my UserType table i have: Admin, Customer Support and Customer. But when I create a User it will create another Customer in a new row in my UserType table.

I have tried:

```
DataContext _context = new DataContext();

UserEntity user = new UserEntity()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Email = "johndoee@example.com",
    PhoneNumber = "1234567890",
    UserType = new UserTypeEntity { Id = 3},
    Address = new AddressEntity { StreetName = "123 Main St", PostalCode = "12345", City = "New York" }
};
```

But I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'
>
> Inner Exception
>
> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UserTypes' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `UserTypeEntity`, hence the Entity Framework tries to create new record to the `UserType` table. In order to prevent this, you have two basic options:

Either: First fetch the values (as `UserTypeEntity` objects) from the `UserType`-table and when creating new `UserEntity`-records, do not create new UserType with `new`, but assign the existing `UserTypeEntity`-object from the fetched values to the `UserType`. E.g.:

```
UserEntity user = new UserEntity()
{
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Doe",
    Email = "johndoee@example.com",
    PhoneNumber = "1234567890",
    UserType = customerType, // object fetched from DB
    Address = new AddressEntity { StreetName = "123 Main St", PostalCode = "12345", City = "New York" }
};
```

Or: in addition to UserType-field of type `UserTypeEntity`, add *foreign key* with the ID-value of type `int`

```
internal class UserEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;

    public int UserTypeId { get; set; } = null!;
    public UserTypeEntity UserType { get; set; } = null!;
    public AddressEntity Address { get; set; } = null!;
    public ICollection<CaseEntity> Cases { get; set; } = new HashSet<CaseEntity>();
    public ICollection<CommentEntity> Comments { get; set; } = new HashSet<CommentEntity>();
}
```

In this case, you initialize the UserTypeId with the correct foreign key value (integer). If the foreign key is something else than UserTypeId, see instructions e.g. [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx?utm_content=cmp-true).